# What is the correct spelling: "filterbank" or "filter bank"

Tags: word-usage, orthography

On Wikipedia, the usage is "filter bank" exclusively.

A [search on Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=filterbank&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=on) returns essentially the same number of both spellings.

This is for a scientific document about digital signal processing, so I want to know which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

A [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=filterbank,filter%20bank&year_start=1990&year_end=2011&corpus=0&smoothing=3) showed that *filter bank* is used more widely:

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=filterbank%2Cfilter%20bank&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1990&year_end=2008

Because of this, I recommend using *filter bank*.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the Ngrams. They will probably be useful again someday.

Answer (score 0):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/filter_bank) gives "filterbank" as an alternative of "filter bank". Personally, the correct spelling is "filter bank" (with a space inbetween) because that's the original.

The only searches on Google that rendered "filterbank" was the name of a product, so I would advise you to use "filter bank" for your paper.